# how to check date records with in fdate and tdate range in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Hi friends i have small doubt in sql server
here i want data based on condition
same id and status is equal to s then that date value  be 
 how to write query in sql server

Table :emp

```
id  |status      |date(mm-dd-yy) |fdate(mm-dd-yy)  |tdate(mm-dd-yy)
 1  | S          |03-16-11       |                 |
 1  | b          |               | 03-15-11        |03-18-11
 1  | s          |03-17-11       |                 |
 1  | b          |               | 04-20-12        |04-30-12
 1  | S          |04-20-12       |                 |
 1  | s          |04-10-12       |                 |
 1  | s          |10-01-14       |                 |
 1  | b          |               |10-02-14         |10-25-14
 2  | s          |01-18-12       |                 |
 2  | b          |               |01-18-12         |01-28-12
 2  | b          |               |03-10-13         |03-24-13
 2  | s          |03-16-13       |                 |
 2  | s          |03-10-13       |                 |
 2  | s          |03-23-13       |                 |
 2  | b          |               |04-20-13         |04-27-13
 2  | s          |07-01-14       |                 |
```

the table (status = s, id, date) compare it with status = b, same id number and date ( Date value from status s) with the date range of fdate and tdate .
if that data with in range then  Billing yes other wise billing no

output like

```
 id  |status      |date(mm-dd-yy) |fdate(mm-dd-yy)  |tdate(mm-dd-yy)   |Billing
 1  | S          |03-16-11       |                 |                   |yes
 1  | s          |03-17-11       |                 |                   |yes
 1  | S          |04-20-12       |                 |                   |yes
 1  | s          |04-10-12       |                 |                   |no
 1  | s          |10-01-14       |                 |                   |no
 2  | s          |01-18-12       |                 |                   |yes
 2  | s          |03-16-13       |                 |                   |yes
 2  | s          |03-10-13       |                 |                   |yes
 2  | s          |03-23-13       |                 |                   |yes
 2  | s          |07-01-14       |                 |                   |no
```

i tried query like below

```
select * 
from ( select * from emp a where status ='s') a
inner join (select * from emp b where status='b') b
    on a.pn=b.pn
where a.date<=b.date1 and a.date>=b.date2
```

its not give exactely result.
please tell me how to write query in sql server .

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select a.Id, 
      a.status, 
      a.date, 
      a.fdate, 
      a.tdate, 
      max(IsNull(case when a.date between b.fDate and b.tDate 
         then 'yes' 
         else 'no' 
      end, 'no')) Billing  
from emp a 
left join emp b 
    on a.Id=b.Id
where a.status ='s'
   and b.status = 'b'
group by a.Id, 
      a.status, 
      a.date, 
      a.fdate, 
      a.tdate
```

Some questions/comments:

- What are the fields: `pn`, `date1` and `date2`?
- date1 in your query is, I guess, bigger than date2